# Whenever I am opening Android Studio it is showing a error Start Failed . Please tell me what can I do in order to start it again

Tags: android-studio

Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.AssertionError: Failed to read C:\Users\91626\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3\updatedBrokenPlugins.db
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.DefaultLogger.error(DefaultLogger.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:232)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.tryReadBrokenPluginsFile(PluginManagerCore.java:260)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.readBrokenPluginFile(PluginManagerCore.java:213)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.getBrokenPluginVersions(PluginManagerCore.java:203)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.DescriptorListLoadingContext.(DescriptorListLoadingContext.kt:25)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader$scheduleLoading$resultDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(PluginDescriptorLoader.kt:381)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:296)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.tryReadBrokenPluginsFile(PluginManagerCore.java:233)
... 10 more

---

Your JRE: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr

I have tried updating android studio reinstalling it and reinstalling jdk too.

Comment: Check the 3rd party plugins that are affecting the startup and remove them.

Comment: can you please elaborate what kind of plugins as i am a beginner. Android studio was kept installed in my laptop for nearly a month ,and then as i opened it up(after a month) , the error showed up

Comment: Try updating the ide to the latest version or clearing caches.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations :) .I tried deleting the updatedBrokenPlugins.db file and it worked